# Printf-like function

Tags: haskell, variadic-functions, function-parameter, polyvariadic

I'm trying to write a function with an arbitrary number of arguments. These arguments can be Int or String. And I have a problem with ints. For some reason (which I don't understand), the value 1 becomes a source of ambiguity. How to deal with this error and what is the source of it?

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
import Data.Typeable

data PackArgTypes = PackInt Int | PackString String
                              deriving Show

class PackArg t where
  toPackArg :: t -> PackArgTypes

instance PackArg Int where
  toPackArg = PackInt . fromIntegral
instance PackArg Integer where
  toPackArg = PackInt . fromIntegral

instance PackArg String where
  toPackArg = PackString

class PackType t where
  pack' :: String -> [PackArgTypes] -> t

instance PackType (IO a) where
  pack' fmt acc = do
    print fmt
    mapM_ print acc
    return undefined

instance (PackArg a, PackType r) => PackType (a -> r) where
    pack' fmt acc = \x -> pack' fmt $ acc ++ [toPackArg x]

pack :: (PackType t) => String -> t
pack fmt = pack' fmt []

main :: IO ()
main = do
  pack "asd" "qwe" "asd"(1 :: Int) -- Ok
  pack "asd" "qwe" "asd" 1         -- Sad
```

In said case I've got the error

```
test1.hs:33:3-6: No instance for (PackArg a0) arising from a use of ‘pack’ …
The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance PackArg String
    -- Defined at /home/knesterov/test1.hs:13:10
  instance PackArg Int -- Defined at /home/knesterov/test1.hs:10:10
In a stmt of a 'do' block: pack "asd" "qwe" "asd" 1
In the expression: do { pack "asd" "qwe" "asd" 1 }
In an equation for ‘main’: main = do { pack "asd" "qwe" "asd" 1 }
test1.hs:33:26: No instance for (Num a0) arising from the literal ‘1’ …
The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
  instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
  instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
  ...plus 7 others
In the fourth argument of ‘pack’, namely ‘1’
In a stmt of a 'do' block: pack "asd" "qwe" "asd" 1
In the expression: do { pack "asd" "qwe" "asd" 1 }
Compilation failed.
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to user5402 who pointed to the difference between ghci and ghc. Ghci enables extension ExtendedDefaultRules by [default](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules)

So with three additional lines my sample works with no errors.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules #-}
instance PackArg Integer where
  toPackArg = PackInt . fromIntegral
```

Comment: Constants are polymorphic in Haskell, `1 :: Num a => a`. So, `1` could also be a pair, or a string, or anything else if someone adds a `Num` instance. Of course, that would be unadvisable, but the compiler has to cope with the possibility that such an instance is added later on, or in another module. I don't think there's a good solution for this issue, and having to add a type annotation is not a very big deal, IMHO.

Comment: IMO, `printf`-like things are neat ways to show off the power of Haskell's type system, but generally bad for writing actual programs or libraries. My best advice on how to write this sort of thing is not to.

Comment: Could you give some details or examples why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
  instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
  ...
```

Recall that the literal `1` can be interpreted as a value any `Num` type, so GHC doesn't know which one to select - e.g. `Int`, `Double`, `Rational`, etc.

The standard `Text.Printf` module has the same problem:

```
import Text.Printf

main = putStrLn $ printf "%d" 3
```

gives he same error.

Note that if you won't get an error if you enter this code into ghci because there are defaulting rules which make the expression `1` monomorphic instead of polymorphic.

Comment: It's because of extension ExtendedDefaultRules, with it your sample with printf will work without errors.